# seperate numbers written in textbox after every two digits with comma vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

[image]

Here is the number chart mentioned above, i want to write the code for my query below :

Controls i have `textbox1`, `label1`, `label2`, `button1`.

I have a `textbox1` which generate random numbers i.e 402045.

I want in `label1` the the following textbox text is displayed as: 40,20,45.

And in `Label2` it will display the values of the comma separated numbers from the chart mention above i.e : the `label2` value would be : PFr.

Sample Code :

```
For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.Text.Length
    ListBox1.Items.Add(i)
    Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 2) & "-"
Next i
```

Comment: pst.. 402045 is **not** an even number

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Dim sChars '--> contain your chars
Dim s as String = Textbox1.text 
Dim s1,s2,s3 as String

sChars = "+-* ..."   ' --> fill this
s1 = mid(s,1,2)
s2 = mid(s,3,2)
s3 = mid(s,5)

Label1.text = s1 & "," & s2 & "," & s3
Label2.text = mid(sChars,val(s1),1) & mid(sChars,val(s2),1) & mid(sChars,val(s3),1)
```

But I think, in this case that Label1.text is not needed !